# Position div entire width of viewport in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, positioning, twitter-bootstrap

How do you style a div in Bootstrap to span the entire width of the viewport (without fixed positioning) within the normal 12-grid system of "rows" and "spans"?

In the Bootstrap source, the `navbar-fixed-top` class achieves this effect using a fixed position and `left` and `right` attributes:

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

However, this navbar stays in the window regardless of scrolling. What styles are necessary to achieve the same entire width of the viewport without fixed positioning?

Comment: Why can't fixed positioning be used? Are you looking for a div that encompasses the whole screen but that can be scrolled away from?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to scroll away from it, i.e. not fixed in the viewport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that effect by stretching the `body` and `html` tags 100% in height and width and then defining a child div to that same width. We do that because width and height are relative, so if we define a div 100% in width/height it will only stretch so far as the `body` and `html` tag. Take a look at this example:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    padding-top:60px;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.huge {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BYLVK/1/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BYLVK/1/).

**Note**: There is some extra height added to the body of the `.huge` div due to the `padding-top` added to the body to make way for the top navbar, if that padding is removed it will become a "true" 100% height and not 100% height + top 60px as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to utilize Bootstrap 3 grid and build full-width layouts (stretching row to the entire viewport width) you should consider two things:

1. Bootstrap's `.row` class sets the margin property to: `margin: 0 -15px;`.
2. Grid content [should be wrapped in a containing element](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to offset the aforesaid margin.

### CSS

```
.container-full-width {
    padding: 0 15px; /* Offset .row's margin */
    width: 100%;
}
/* Optional. See comment below. */
.row {
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 70px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container-full-width">
    <div class="row">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
...
</body>
```

Bear in mind that the `.row` elements will have no margin, but it can be fixed by overriding the padding property of the `.row` class and setting the expected margin.

Alternatively you could consider overriding `.row` class and offsetting a margin value, but this requires setting different values for different media/device types.

It is worth checking whether it works in Bootstrap 2 likewise.